# Could Toolkit Namespace - C#

Tags: c#, controls

I recently got to experimenting with the Cloud-Toolkit controls in my Applications i develop for customers, however adding the controls is easy(Simply add the dll) but when building the solution it seems i'm getting a stating i'm missing a namespace reference, what could it be ? The toolkit did not come with any instructions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact error. E. g. which namespace is missing?

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thank you though